# How to add bootstrap like prepend in jQuery Mobile input?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap we can prepend an input using the following code:

```
<div class="input-prepend">
  <span class="add-on">@</span>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

I want to achieve exactly the same thing in jQuery Mobile, but without using bootstrap.
I can see that the relevant CSS code from bootstrap is as follows:

```
.input-prepend {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.input-prepend .add-on {
    background-color: #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 20px;
    line-height: 20px;
    min-width: 16px;
    padding: 4px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
    width: auto;
}
```

After adding these to my custom CSS, I still couldn't figure out what's missing. But certainly something is missing.
Can someone please guide me.
Here is the example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LittleLebowski/Mgq9W/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave the rest of the css the same, but add this to .input-prepend .add-on rule. You could also use vertical-align:top. I tested it using your fiddle link.

```
.input-prepend .add-on {
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the working fiddle for reference to anyone looking for the same solution: http://jsfiddle.net/LittleLebowski/Mgq9W/4/

Answer (score 0):

You could also try adding..

```
.input-prepend input {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: That's not working. Check the fiddle out: http://jsfiddle.net/LittleLebowski/Mgq9W/